# snmp service can't run correctly my program .. in linux

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp, network-monitoring, net-snmp

I have developed this script program  : (program name is x1)

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/top -n 1 >/tmp/top1.log
echo ok
```

Next is the command that I run it on terminal and get correct reply:

```
./x1
```

meaning that when external command of  `top -n 1>tmp/top1.log` is written in the file top1.log and then the message ok printed in output!

But, if I config the snmpd.cof and the program is run by snmp service:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 127.0.0.0    OID
```

The external command of `top -n 1>/tmp/top1.log` will not be placed in top1.log and the file top1.log will not be generated, only the message ok is printed in the output.

In fact, `top -n 1>/tmp/top1.log` command cannot run by SNMP service.

Comment: How have you configured the snmpd.conf file.  You should show that part too.

Comment: syslocation Server Room
syscontact Sysadmin (root@localhost)

rwcommunity public 192.168.7.165
rwcommunity public 127.0.0.1

sh  1.3.6.1.4.1.999.4.1.4  public  /tmp/x1
i used ( sh and exec ) to run !

Comment: What exactly do you expect your code should do? Pls Detail, detail...

Answer (score 0):

my snmpd.conf :

```
syslocation Server Room
syscontact Sysadmin (root@localhost)

rwcommunity public 192.168.7.165
rwcommunity public 127.0.0.1

sh  1.3.6.1.4.1.999.4.1.4  public  /tmp/x1
```

i used ( sh and exec ) to run !